# Does UTC date string require the format specifier "Z" even if that string includes time offset?

Tags: javascript, parsing, date, utc

For instance,

```
const d = new Date("2012-08-20T15:00:00-07:00");
```

`d` here is a *UTC* time with time offset = `07:00`. Does it still require `Z` like this `2012-08-20T15:00:00-07:00Z`? Is this correct?

If I take this string with `Z` and parse it using `Date.parse()` method in JavaScript, it throws an error. Not sure what is wrong!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, you should not include the "Z" with a time zone offset.

From [rfc3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt):

```
  Z           A suffix which, when applied to a time, denotes a UTC
              offset of 00:00; often spoken "Zulu" from the ICAO
              phonetic alphabet representation of the letter "Z".
```

The "Z" is a zero time offset, so including it with an explicit offset (especially a non-zero one) doesn't makes sense.

Comment: Is there any javascript function to find out if the date string has this offset added or not? Or do i just use regular expressions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of JavaScript has an easier way to check this than using a regex.

Answer (score 14):

Quoting [W3C note on Date and Time Formats](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime):

> YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
>
> where:
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)
> ```

Notice the *or* word above. You *either* specify time zone offset *or* `Z` for *Zulu* (no offset).

Comment: The Z actually stands for Zero.  The word Zulu is just the NATO phonetic way to say "Z", not the other way around.

Comment: @TedBigham That is incorrect, Z does not stand for zero. Each time zone offset was assigned a letter from the alphabet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones

Comment: @speedymcs The point is that Z doesn't stand for Zulu. It's just 'Z' which is the 00:00 time zone. Yes it's also called Zulu because of the 'Z', but not the other way around.  If for some crazy reason the 'Z' time zone was named Pumpkin, it would still be a 'Z' here, not a 'P'.  I guess "stands for" was not the right term.

Comment: @TedBigham You stated that Z stands for zero, my point was to correct that. I agree with the rest!