# converting string to epoch with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript
and have the following  string `'2023-06-19 05:00:00.554'` and want to convert it to epoch i am trying something like this

```js
var s = "2023-06-19 05:00:00.554";
var epoch = new Date(s).getTime();

console.log(epoch);
```

but it give wrong results any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: What result does it give an what result are you expecting?

Comment: What do you mean by 'convert it to epoch'?

Comment: Without specifying timezone, `new Date()` default to your system timezone. If you want to mean UTC+0, you have to explicitly write it in the string

Answer (score 0):

As explained by **Ricky Mo** you must specify the timezone value of your date,
otherwise the system will use the host system's timezone at this date (with STD or DST calculation).

2 ways

```
var s = "2023-06-19T05:00:00.554+00:00"
// or
var s = "2023-06-19T05:00:00.554Z" //  Zulu time zone
```

> thanks to **Darryl Noakes**  for reminding me `Z` (stand for "Zulu" from the ICAO) (but I remember more easily the notation with the positive  `+` or negative `-` sign with the value of the time difference in `±hh:mm`)

```js
var s = "2023-06-19T05:00:00.554+00:00";  // GMT 0 -> + 0h, 0mn
var epoch = new Date(s).getTime();

console.log(epoch); //  1687150800554 everywhere in the world!
```

Comment: You can also use the `Z` suffix instead of `+00:00` if you use ISO timestamps. Not sure about non-ISO ones.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714548/does-utc-date-string-require-the-format-specifier-z-even-if-that-string-includ/14714611#14714611

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have string `"2023-06-19 05:00:00.554"` and it represents GMT, you need to first convert that to a [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format string, so that it can be converted to a Date object reliably, regardless of the browser used. The ISO format of your input is `"2023-06-19T05:00:00.554Z"`

Code using a regex to convert your input to the ISO format:

```js
const s = "2023-06-19 05:00:00.554";
let epoch = new Date(s.replace(/ (.*)$/, 'T$1Z')).getTime();
console.log(epoch); // output: 1687150800554
```